# Imagick can't open RAW file

Tags: php, imagick

I'm trying to open `ARW` (Sony raw image format) file with Imagick like below:

```
$imgOriginal =new Imagick();
file_put_contents($mptFile, $response->body);
$imgOriginal->setformat(strtolower(str_replace(".", "",$_typeFile)));            
$imgOriginal->readimage(__DIR__. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$mptFile);
```

File itself is downloaded from amazon s3, placed on local disk and then I'm trying to convert it to jpeg. Everything works fine on Windows, but when I run that code on Linux server (Amazon EC2 instance), I'm getting error like below (`readimage` throws it):

> Message: unable to open image `/tmp/magick-XX3txRwQ.ppm': No such file
>   or directory @ blob.c/OpenBlob/2480

Originally, I were using `readimageblob` instead of `readimage`, but getting same issue with it.

It looks to me like it can't create some kind of temporary file, but I have nothing like `open_basedir` being set and `/tmp` folder is opened to everyone (its permission: `drwxrwxrwx  3 root root`)

At the same time, it works fine with JPEG files.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I've figured out that I had no `ufraw-batch` tool being installed on my linux machine. And that is a tool which actually does RAW image processing.

I've installed it and now everything works fine to me.

Comment: For macOS users using brew: `brew install ufraw`

Comment: I have the same problem and installing ufraw or dcraw doesn't solve it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be available on Ubuntu 22.04?